# ASUS motherboard delayed power on, is this normal?

Tags: motherboard, power

My new ASUS Prime Z590-A motherboard has a delay when I press the chassis power on button.

After I press it, I see some leds light in the mobo, but then a 3-4 sec delay follows, not even the PSU (at least its fan) powered and power led in the power button also **not** lighting. After a 3-4 seconds, all the fans start, the power button led lights, and the normal power on sequence starts.

**Question:**

Is this normal, or should I contact the shop?

Comment: Do you cut power to the PC when it is off, for example using a power strip or by pulling the plug?

Comment: Definitely no. The PC is plugged in, and also the PSU switch on the back never touched